# SublimeCodeIntel Memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, editor, sublimetext2

When I use Sublime with *sublimecodeintel* package while writing code or plain text, it is using ~1.2GB of Memory and 0% CPU. I observed the behaviour of memory usage and it seems that every time I type a word memory usage jumps ~1MB.
If I set `"codeintel": false,` the memory usage returns back to normal.
This seems to be a memory leak issue to me. Is there any way that I an fix this?

here are my settings for sublimecodeintel (I use default settings)

```
/*
    SublimeCodeIntel default settings
*/
{
    /*
        Sets the mode in which SublimeCodeIntel runs:

        true - Enabled (the default).
        false - Disabled.
    */
    "codeintel": true,

    // An array of language names which are disabled.
    "codeintel_disabled_languages":
    [
    ],

    /*
        Sets the mode in which SublimeCodeIntel's live autocomplete runs:

        true - Autocomplete popups as you type (the default).
        false - Autocomplete popups only when you request it.
    */
    "codeintel_live": true,

    // An array of language names to disable.
    "codeintel_live_disabled_languages":
    [
    ],

    /*
        Maps syntax names to languages. This allows variations on a syntax
        (for example "Python (Django)") to be used. The key is
        the base filename of the .tmLanguage syntax files, and the value
        is the syntax it maps to.
    */
    "codeintel_syntax_map":
    {
        "Python Django": "Python"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest fix is to set `"codeintel":false,` unfortunately. If you head over to [Github](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) and check out the Issues, you'll see that a number of people have problems with performance, especially on large projects. The plugin was originally ported from [Open Komodo Editor](http://www.openkomodo.com/) to Sublime, and I think some performance was lost in translation. I don't have any problem with it whilst working on small projects, but if I start using IPython with `pylab` in [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) (which imports very large parts of `numpy` and `matplotlib`, among others) then performance can slow to a crawl - and this is on a quad-core 3.4 GHz i7 with 20GB RAM, so I'm not starving for power.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like any of the performance Issues have been responded to, let alone addressed in the code, so if someone is willing to profile and fix it we'd all be grateful!

Comment: I agree that it would be great if someone -preferably some developer from SublimeCodeIntel project- would come up with a fix. Despite its usefulness, this is a critical issue.